# Is there an interval notation for complex numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers, notation

Just as $$\{x \in \mathbb{R}:  a \leq  x \leq b\}$$ can be written in the more-compact form $[a,b],$ is there an analogous notation for $$\{z \in \mathbb{C}:z=x+yi, x \in[a,b], y \in[c,d]\} \quad ?$$

Pictorially, the set of all  $z \in \mathbb{C}$ lying in the green area is the set that I'd like to express in a more concise form:
[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Maybe just define something as $[a,b]+[c,d]i$ ?

Comment: Maybe, but not the + sign.

Comment: @RokKralj Why not? There exists [interval arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic), which we can do on real numbers, why not to do it on complex?

Comment: Because you can do it in the real numbers, it wouldn't be obvious that you mean this to be complex numbers.

Comment: @Teepeemm We choose one real value from $[c,d]$, multiplying it by $i$ we get imaginary number, then adding any real from interval $[a,b]$ we get complex number. Quite obvious, isn't it?

Comment: @Somnium If I were to use this notation, would it be more sensible to write $z \in [a,b]+[c,d]i$ or $z \in \{[a,b]+[c,d]i\}$?

Comment: @alexqwx it's not a matter of being sensible, they mean different things! The former (probably needing round brackets) makes $z$ a complex number, the latter makes it an interval.

Comment: It is common to define $X \oplus Y = \{x+y | x \in X, y \in Y\}$ and $\alpha X = \{\alpha x | x \in X\}$. So, $[a,b] \oplus [c,d]i$ seems like reasonable notation.

Comment: I think that cartesian product ($\times$) would make much more sense than $+$. Plus somehow implies that the operator result type is the same as operand type.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 It is common to define $X+Y = \{x+y:x\in X, y\in Y\}$ IMHO. There's no need to introduce an extra symbol for that.

Comment: @Teepeemm It's not interval arithmetics, it's simply set arithmetics with addition and multiplication, and you can do this over any ring, right?

Answer (score 17):

Perhaps $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: \operatorname{Re}(z) \in [a,b], \; \operatorname{Im}(z) \in [c,d]\}$.

The complex numbers have no inherent order, so unless you invent something like $[[a+ci, b+di]]$ I know no more compact way to write this.

Comment: @Alizter: thanks for improving the format of my answer. I didn't know how to get Re() and Im() in normal style, and I suppose I was too lazy to look it up.

Answer (score 15):

As far as I know there is no widely recognized standard notation. **Define one** in your paper/book/essay if you need it often.

Comment: +1.  Do not just use a notation and expect the reader to know what it means.

Comment: @GEdgar Better one: Do not introduce notation unless you are 111% sure you need it and it makes your paper easier to follow.

Answer (score 11):

Since $\mathbb C$ is just $\mathbb R^2$ with specific operations, the notation $[a,b]\times[c,d]$ obviously do the trick.

Comment: This is correct in a sense, but likely to be misleading unless explained.  Whether $\mathbb{C}$ "is" $\mathbb{R}^2$ depends on your personal view of the foundations, and readers who prefer to define $\mathbb{C}$ in a different way may be confused.

Comment: I admit that the "just" in my answer was a bit provocative...

Answer (score 5):

Well, Cartesian product could work here, $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\Re(z)\in[a,b],\Im(z)\in[c,d]\}$ as $[a,b]\times[ic,id]$.

But I've never seen a standardized notation for something like this, except for circular regions, such as $|z+1|<4$.

Comment: Similar to denoting a set by $|z+1|<4$, you could write $a<Re z<b, c<Im z<d$.

Comment: I do not think it works. First of all, an element of the set $[a,b]\times [ic,id]$ is a pair $(x,iy)$, which is not usually canonically identified with a complex number. Then, $[ic,id]$ means nothing in my opinion since you can't define an ordering for imaginary numbers; $i[c,d]$ would look better, but still dubious. Overall, I'd say **do not use it** unless you define it in advance.

Comment: Yeah, that was something I was having trouble with, figuring out how to define that the second set is imaginary.

Answer (score 5):

During the Complex Analysis course I took we used
$$[z,w]:=\{(1-t)z+tw:t\in[0,1]\},\quad z,w\in\mathbb{C},$$
which coincides with normal intervals when $z,w\in\mathbb{R}$. But you should define this yourself, because people won't know what you mean if you don't.

Comment: This is a line segment connecting $z$ and $w$, not the rectangle.

Comment: This is a pretty common notation, at least in analytic number theory.

Comment: +1 This just shows that defining a complex interval to be a rectangle doesn't sound like a great idea...

Answer (score 4):

You could write it like this:

$\{(x + yi) \in \mathbb{C}: x \in [a,b], \; y \in [c,d]\}$.

Alternatively, choose one of these:

$[a,b] \times i[c,d]$

$[a,b] \times [ic,id]$

Comment: You could even drop the $\in \mathbb{C}$, since the inclusion could be inferred from the fact $x$ and $y$ are reals.

Answer (score 3):

A teacher of mine once used an "interval notation" for boxes in $\Bbb R^n$. If $\vec{a} = (a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ and $\vec{b} = (b_1, \cdots, b_n)$, then: $$]\vec{a}, \vec{b}[ = ]a_1, b_1[ \times \cdots \times ]a_n, b_n[ = \prod_{i = 1}^n ]a_i, b_i[$$
Maybe you can adapt it for what you need.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not the answer you're looking for, but you can include the picture and then write:

> [image: X]
>
> Let $X$ be a rectangle in the complex plane, as depicted.